# Find Nearby App: Unable to locate my accounts or use Map Accounts button

Tags: apex, visualforce, appexchange, app

I am very exited to use this [app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001gpWhEAI), but it's not working when I install it in my dev org.

1. When I click on Map Accounts button in list view its jumping to fn.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/maperror_badlistview page
2. When Click on locate 'Find Nearby: Locate Account' Its jumping to fn.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/AGeoCode?id=###########
   saying Its loading bit never closes

Any tips or documentation for getting this setup?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it wasn't properly configured.  Navigate to the Application and go through the steps in the Setup Guide tab.